# hibernate mysql problems

Tags: mysql, hibernate

there are 2 things i wish to do mysql database from hibernate.cfg.xml;

1. To have utf8 characters so it can save character č,ć,ž,đ,š and repoduse them as thay are, not as ? in tapestry application.
2. fix for the com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

> No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was
>   implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error: ** BEGIN NESTED
>   EXCEPTION ** com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
>   MESSAGE: The last packet successfully received from the server
>   was48709 milliseconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 48709 milliseconds ago, which is longer than the server
>   configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either
>   expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your
>   application, increasing the server configured values for client
>   timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property
>   'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

my hibermate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/200</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Print SQL to stdout. -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">false</property>

    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping class="domaci.entities.Korisnik"/>
    <mapping class="domaci.entities.Magazin"/>
    <mapping class="domaci.entities.Rubrika"/>
    <mapping class="domaci.entities.Strana"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, in your cfg file for that č,ć,ž,đ,š characters you need to set character set to utf-8 also:

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

or something like this,..., I'm not really into this hibernate stuff but I know that you need to do this. "**charset=utf-8**"

Answer (score 0):

also have Increased server timeout with next commands:

```
set @@global.wait_timeout=31536000 
set @@session.wait_timeout=31536000
```